# Disk Utility and Startup Disk pane not loading discs or partitions

Tags: bootcamp, disk-utility, startup, high-sierra

I'm running on a late-2016 MacBook Pro with macOS 10.13.3 High Sierra. I recently created and installed a Bootcamp partition.

Since installing Windows, both Disk Utility and the Startup Disk pane in System Preferences never load anything or do not believe in the existence of any discs at all, respectively.

Disk Utility simply does this:

[image: Disk utility doing nothing]

However, when booting to the Recovery partition using `Command + R`, I'm able to access Disk Utility there, which reports the existence of both the APFS and NTFS partitions.

And the Startup Disk pane simply reports that there are no startup discs at all:

[image: Denying reality]

Yet, when using the chooser when booting with `Option`, it shows the two start up discs perfectly (though for some reason it insists on choosing the Windows one even when apparently using `Command + Enter` should change the default).

The macOS reboot switcher/start up disc selector in Windows is of a different mind as well. It only recognises the existence of itself, while the macOS one believes none exist, and the UEFI selector shows the existence of all.

Comment: Start by posting the output from the command `diskutil list`.

Comment: I’m going to close the question for the time being, well unless this re-emerges after I reinstall macOS and attempt the repartitioning. Insofar as I’ve basically obliterated the old install, there’s going to not be any ability to get information to resolve this now-irrelevant problem.